# Revision control , Build and deploy. production code vs test code

Tags: spring, deployment, version-control, build

Our project is comprised of a single war file (web application)

We have a master branch in our git repository that contains all the source files for it.

We are use a staging (test) environment and a production env.

both should be configured differently.

So our problem is:

When we push new features to the git repository, and building the war file. it consists data that is staging-specific. so we actually cant deploy this war in production.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?  (the files that change from prod to test are for example:
spring config files, other config files, some xmls, etc)

one naive solution is to have 2 branches (one for production the other for testing) but that sounds really cumbersome.

Comment: Google for "Spring Profile".

Comment: Personally I use chef to control application configuration files. That way my configuration is under revision control and the details are specified at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

For the long run:

Try to extract the specific settings from the spring context files, and make them parameter of your application that are configured in the application server.

For example the database connection settings: Configure a Database Connection in the application server and make them aviable via JNDI. Then your application can obtain the Database Connection from JNDI. So your application is independed of your concrete database connection settings.

You can use the same technique for other configuration. And of course you can use it to enable/disabe Spring Profiles.